# Jelastic Docker with Spring Boot and Netflix libraries

Tags: jelastic

Does the Jelastic Docker environment support the deployment of Spring Boot jars?   I can't find any docs on this.

Also would it suit Spring Boot apps built to use the Netflix tech stack - Zuul, Feign, Eureka etc

Comment: Could you provide the details about your hosting provider? 
Do you have specific Docker container which you want to run? Or are you looking for it?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Jelastic Docker environment support the deployment of Spring Boot jars

Jelastic supports all the features that are provided by the selected docker image. But, if you want to use Jelastic GUI deployment, you need to use native Java environment. You can find more information in the [official documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/upload-deploy-application).